# Powershell fails to wait for curl to complete upload

Tags: powershell, curl

I'm using curl to upload a file to the cloud. The problem is that, the script immediately removes the local file before the curl operation was completed. The weird thing is when I put the `& curl.exe` and `Remove-Item` in a separate ps1 file and test it there, it works properly and the file is removed after uploading it.

The following code is from `main.ps1` (executed on start-up from cmd), which checks my inputfolder every 5 seconds for new files

```
while ($true) {
    Get-ChildItem -Path $inputFolder -Filter "*$extIn" | ForEach-Object {

        & ffmpeg.exe -i $inFile ...some operations $outFile

        if ($LASTEXITCODE -eq 0) {
            #credentials
            $lg = ...
            #curl upload operation
            & curl.exe -T "$outFile" -g -u $lg -k https://mycloud/
            Write-Host "Done uploading: $outFile"
            #removing item
            Remove-Item -LiteralPath $inFile -Force
            Write-Host "Removed input file!"
        } else {
            Write-Error "Conversion failed!"
        } 
    }
    sleep 5
}
```

I used `curl.exe` because it gave me an error when I used only `curl` (I don't know if this is relevant):

```
Invoke-WebRequest : Parameter cannot be processed because the parameter name 'T' is ambiguous. Possible matches include ...
```

On a sidenote: I tried the same script (but using `curl -T ...`) on my other pc which runs on ubuntu 16.04. No problems there. The script will eventually be used on a ubuntu 16.04/17.10, but in the meantime it needs to work on my windows pc.

Any bit of help is appreciated.

Comment: One of the default aliases in PowerShell is for `Invoke-WebRequest` as `curl`.  `wget` is one, too.  Yes, a lot of people find this annoying.  Calling `curl.exe` or `wget.exe` forces the system to call the executable rather than the command.

Comment: If you are using powershell is there some reason you cannot use `Invoke-WebRequest` directly?  It has tons of options to download a file.

Comment: Well I thought if my `curl` works on my ubuntu, why need something else? Besides, I don't know how to use `Invoke-WebRequest` (yet). Also, the main problem is not that the curl itself isn't working or that I need another command to upload a file, it's that the file is removed before uploading was completed.

Answer (score 1):

Can try

```
Start-Process <path to exe> -NoNewWindow -Wait
```

or

```
$proc = Start-Process <path to exe> -NoWindow
$proc.WaitForExit()
```

Either of these should wait for the process to complete. You can also try adding this to the end of your line where calling curl, a pipe and Wait-Process

```
| Wait-Process
```

Comment: This only works for me in my separate file, not in my `main.ps1`

Comment: See: Get-Help -Name Start-Process.   Synopsis
    Starts one or more processes on the local computer.

Description
    The Start-Process cmdlet starts one or more processes on the local computer. To specify the program that runs in the process, enter an executable file or script file, or a file that can be opened by using a program on the computer. If you specify a non-executable file, Start-Process starts the program that is associated with the file, similar to the Invoke-Item cmdlet.

Answer (score 0):

As for:
"I used curl.exe because it gave me an error when I used only curl (I don't know if this is relevant):"

It is because in PoSH commands like curl, wget are all aliases for PoSH cmdlets. You can use these commands but you have to use what PoSH allows.

```
Get-Alias -Name curl
CommandType     Name 
Alias           curl -> Invoke-WebRequest

(Get-Command -Name Invoke-WebRequest).Parameters
Get-Help -Name Invoke-WebRequest -Examples
Get-Help -Name Invoke-WebRequest -Full
```

PoSH has a lots of aliases, and as you discovered, you have to use an .exe to get the real thing or remove the alias. PoSH will always use native cmdlets first before making any call to an external command, unless you tell it to.

Show all aliases

```
Get-Alias
```

Consider using PoSH WorkFlow

Getting Started with Windows PowerShell Workflow
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj134242(v=ws.11).aspx

A workflow is a sequence of programmed, connected steps that perform long-running tasks or require the coordination of multiple steps across multiple devices or managed nodes. Windows PowerShell Workflow lets IT pros and developers author sequences of multi-device management activities, or single tasks within a workflow, as workflows. By design, workflows can be long-running, repeatable, frequent, parallelizable, interruptible, stoppable, and restartable. They can be suspended and resumed; they can also continue after an unexpected interruption, such as a network outage or computer restart.

Windows PowerShell: PowerShell scripts versus PowerShell workflows
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn151046.aspx

PowerShell Workflows: Nesting
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/01/09/powershell-workflows-nesting